# Permission denied (publickey) error when using Git?

Tags: git, github, git-push

I'm trying to push my project after git commit but i face an error:

```
git push
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for RSA "/home/acer/.ssh/id_rsa" from agent: agent refused operation
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Is wired because i push other changes before on the same project and this error is present only in this one!!!!

Comment: Googling "Permission denied (publickey)" gives the first hit at https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/error-permission-denied-publickey. I suggest following the instructions there to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: Can you check your id_rsa is a valid private key? e.g. you could try `openssl rsa -in id_rsa` to see if openssl will accept it. It might be simplest to generate a new key and upload the new public key to github.

Comment: What operating system are you using?  Can you edit your question to include the output of `env | grep '^SSH'` in a code block?

Comment: Make sure your ssh key has restricted permissions (`chmod 600 keyname`).

Answer (score 8):

Solved thanks to `$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: Anyone know what this actually does?

Comment: This would add the ssh key into the aah-agent. You can read more about it from it's manual: `man ssh-add` or info pages: `info ssh-add`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I can expand the [very brief answer of Sébastien Serre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71335885/1613005).

So when you copy private and public ssh keys you have to also tell the ssh-agent where to find the key. For this reason you can to use `ssh-add`. But this would fail if the permissions are not correctly set. So here are the steps you have to do:

For the sake of this answer I assume the place you want to store the keys are in `~/.ssh/` and your private key is named `id_rsa` and public key is named `id_rsa.pub`.

**1.** Copy the private **and** public keys to the desired folder:

```bash
mv id_rsa ~/.ssh/
mv id_rsa.pub ~/.ssh/
```

**2.** Have correct permissions (this is good for security and also prevents errors in the next step):

```bash
chmod 700 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
chmod 744 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

- `700` means read+write+execute for you and any other account cannot access
- `744` means read+write+execute for you and any other account can only read.

**3.** Add the ssh key to the ssh-agent:

```bash
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

You will be asked for the password of the key. when You enter the password correct, you are good to go.

Comment: Faced the same issue as TS, but got another error whily trying ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa: Error loading key "/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa": error in libcrypto